# Python - tempfile module creates a file that cannot be opened?

Tags: python, imagemagick, temporary-files

I'm using the `tempfile` module and `imagemagick` and when i try to run this code:

```
width = height = 100
temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
canvas = "convert -size {}x{} canvas:black {}/canvas.png".format(scale_width, scale_height, temp_file.name)
os.system(canvas)
```

I get the following error:

> convert: unable to open image
>   `/var/folders/jn/phqf2ygs0wlgflgfvvv0ctbw0009tb/T/tmpeMcIuh/canvas.png':
>   Not a directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2705. convert: WriteBlob
>   Failed`
>   /var/folders/jn/phqf2ygs0wlgflgfvvv0ctbw0009tb/T/tmpeMcIuh/canvas.png'
>   @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1630.

What could be the problem?
I'm just trying to create a black image (resolution of 100x100) stored in a randomly generated temp file.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105904/python-subprocess-pipe-an-image-blob-to-imagemagick-shell-command/30109768#30109768

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I also thought about mentioning that, but the OP explicitly states "randomly generated temp file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to leave the `/canvas.png` bit. The temporary file created by `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` was `/var/folders/jn/phqf2ygs0wlgflgfvvv0ctbw0009tb/T/tmpeMcIuh`. So using it as parent directory for the output file raises the error by imagemagick.

To specify the output format PNG by filename extension, the temporary file can be created with the `suffix` keyword argument:

```
temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.png')
```

Additionally, you should use the `subprocess` module to run subprocesses. That way you do not have to use string formatting the whole command in order to pass the subprocesses' arguments, e.g.

```
subprocess.check_call(['convert',
                       '-size', '{}x{}'.format(scale_width, scale_height),
                       'canvas:black',
                       temp_file.name])
```

And another remark: `NamedTemporaryFile()` opens a file descriptor, which you should close right away. The docs also state that you are in charge of deleting the file again.

Comment: but then how could i tell imagemagick i want a .png file named a certain way in that location?

Comment: `NamedTemporaryFile()` has a `suffix` keyword argument. Answer edited accordingly.

Comment: Close the file descriptor right away? Then there's the inconsistency with the `mkstemp` return value being a tuple. Doesn't the `tempfile` API seem a little wonky to be included in the standard library?